# Sub domain gets redirected to main domain every time i try to get into subdomain

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I had deployed by weather-app on this domain www.angularweb.tech,
next to avoid any confusion i gave my another app that is news-app a subdomain called news.angularweb.tech and similarly weather.angularweb.tech for weather-app.

hence i directed by main page that is profile page to www.angularweb.tech. this sites has my main profile page from here i have provided links to weather.angularweb.tech and news.angularweb.tech inside button component of bootstrap. now whenever i click on weather-app button it either gets redirected to news.angularweb.tech or reloads my profile page. 
Hence it isnt possible to visit weather.angularweb.tech.

i will provide by server configuration code which is written inside default file of sites-enabled folder.

```
     #server block
    server{
    server_name www.angularweb.tech;
    return 301 http://angularweb.tech$request_uri;
    }



    server{
    server_name angularweb.tech;
    root /home/ubuntu/frontend/projects-profile;




   location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    #this will allow you to refresh page in your angular app
    }
    }



    #server block
     server{
     return 301 http://news.angularweb.tech$request_uri;
      }



    server{
    server_name news.angularweb.tech;
    root /home/ubuntu/frontend/news-app;




   location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    #this will allow you to refresh page in your angular app
    }
    }

    #server block
     server{


     return 301 http://weather.angularweb.tech$request_uri;
     }



    server{
    server_name weather.angularweb.tech;
    root /home/ubuntu/frontend/weather-app;




   location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    #this will allow you to refresh page in your angular app
    }
    }
```

Comment: You have multiple server blocks with no `server_name`. You can test and view the configuration that Nginx is actually reading by using `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`).

Comment: i got this when i enter nginx -T cmd in terminal                                                            ubuntu@ip-172-31-46-236:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ nginx -T
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2019/06/25 14:06:20 [warn] 1688#1688: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in 
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed